# USB memory stick with real-time auditing

Tags: usb

There are several black boxes with just a USB socket and I'd like to find out which data they read from a USB memory stick when plugged-in in real time. A plus would be if I could hook-in like a debugger and manipulate the file system contents of the USB stick while the stick is read by the black box.

```
+--------------+                    
|              |                    +-----------------+
|  Black Box   |   +------------+   | RT-Information  |
|  with       +----+ USB-Stick  |   | on remote Device|
|  USB socket +----+            +---+-+-------------+-+
|              |   +------------+     |>>> $        |
+--------------+                      +-------------+
```

High- or low level: On a high level assuming exFAT, it would for example interesting for me to see if directory listings are accessed and file opens as well as data reads in a file. On the other hand if there is hardware supporting low-level output of its accesses, it might not be too hard, to write some software that translates those low-level information into high-level info that I am seeking.

I have nearly no clue about how hardware communicates over USB.

Comment: At the expensive end of things, a hardware USB analyzer will do most of what you want for hundreds to thousands of dollars.  No idea if there's anything cheaper.

Comment: That's quite a lot -- too much for a hobby, IMHO. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283147/177226 suggests a BeagleBone Black for instance coming with a OTG USB port using USB gadget software to emulate the mass-storage or use the pre-configured (seems like when you connect it to PC it identifies as both mass storage and networking device) -- and then I would need to find some analyser software for Linux.